# Символ $ в названии переменной

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Хочу прочитать JSON-файл, но возникла проблема: некоторые имена в файле имеют символ `$` в названии, что приводит к ошибке "Недопустимый символ в названии"

Подскажите, как быть в таком случае?

Использую `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Часть файла:

```
$date: {
   $numberLong: "1493325863000"
}
```

P.S.: Не хочу писать каждый раз что-то вроде `obj["$date"]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `JsonPropertyAttribute` для того, чтобы указать, какое имя должно использоваться при сериализации/десериализации.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyDate
{
    [JsonProperty("$numberLong")]
    public string NumberLongStr { get; set; }

    public long NumberLong
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(NumberLongStr);
        }

        set
        {
            NumberLongStr = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Я не проверяю значение `NumberLongStr` перед парсингом, код приведён только как демонстрация.